# Android Studio 2.0 instant run not working but appear this tips?

Tags: android, android-studio-2.0, android-instant-run

When click the instant run,appear below tips:

> you currently have an active Run session of the same launch
>   configuration,do you want to kill the session and proceed with the
>   current launch

Anyone else can solve the issue? thanks!

Comment: Do you use proguard in your project?

Comment: no use, when I first install the as 2.0,it is correct and run well,then it never do not work

Comment: please check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37207831/2826147) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35169716/2826147) answer.

Answer (score 5):

It might be because you updated your Android Studio Canary build without updating Gradle.
You should probably update the gradle plugin. Even I had the same problem updating gradle plugin brought back the "Instant Run" feature.

To update the gradle plugin

1. Go to "Setting/Preferences" (File->Setting/Prefrences)
2. Under the "Build, Execution and Deployment" find "Instant Run (or could just search for it).
3. On the top there will be a option to update the gradle plugin, click on and apply. You will get the "Instant Run" feature.
   [image: Instant Run]

Comment: Still not working, please share your .gradle file here, mine is

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha3'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.20.1'
        classpath 'net.researchgate:gradle-release:2.0.2'
    }
}

Comment: I have figured it out the issus.

Comment: @Build3r hi, I tried this out but it is not working... please help me out... what could be the other possible reason?

Comment: add this line also in bulid.gradle                                                    dexOptions {
        maxProcessCount 4 // this is the default value
        javaMaxHeapSize "2g"
    }

Answer (score 1):

Just got a same problem,and fixed by these simple step:

1.Go to '**run/debug configurations**' remove your **android application configuration**

2.Recreate an **android application configuration**

3.Go to **miscellaneous tab**, unchek '**force stop running application before launching activity**'

and it should be work :D

Comment: I have degrade the android studio edition to 1.5.1,do you know why appear this problem?

Comment: I have followed the same steps, however, i am observing the same issue. I am using gradle alpha3 & preview4 versions.

Answer (score -2):

After several attempts at testing, I finally found a solution. As long as the screen remains on, this message will never appear.

> you currently have an active Run session of the same launch configuration,do you want to kill the session and proceed with the current launch

Comment: you don't make any sense... what are you trying to say ?

Comment: Please use proper sentences..(I'm not criticizing you..don't take it that hard!) Remember, a lot of people around here won't understand you if you write that way.